# How to access AWS API after integrated with cognito user pool

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have created API for my Lambda function and tested URL in postman, I am able to view the response. 
Now, for security purpose I have integrated Cognito user pool authorizers to my API.Now I tried to use API and getting response as below

```
{
    "message": "Unauthorized"
}
```

I am having App client id and App client secret for my cognito user pool.Now,I need help for authenticating the API using postman.

Comment: Did you follow this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-invoke-api-integrated-with-cognito-user-pool.html ?

Comment: Thanks Vishal. As per your suggestion I have Implemented the signup and Signin and able to get Accesstoken. Now I used that accesstoken to access my API still I am getting the same error message "Unauthorized". Please let me know what I need to do.

Comment: You probably need to provide more details like what exception/logs are seeing when you getting Unauthorizer exception. But you should look at cloudwatch logs for your ApiGateway api to identify why is it not working as expected.

Comment: Thank You Vishal. After I changed AccessToken with ID Token in Authorisation header my API is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the specific resource method configuration you may need to send the ID Token instead of the Access Token. It took some careful reading of the AWS docs [Integrate an API with a User Pool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html). Steps 6 and 7 are the key to determine which token should be sent. A summary is:

If on the secured Resource Method (Method Execution step) the `OAuth Scopes` setting is set to `NONE` an ID Token should be sent. If a scope value is entered an Access Token should be sent.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have selected None in OAuth Scopes. So I understand that I need to send ID Token to validate my API. I tried to fetch ID Token and now I am trying to test in PostMan. In URL providing API Gateway URL and in Header Added Key name as Authorization and Value as TokenID which I am getting from my JavaScript. Still I am getting the response  as below.                 {
    "message": "Unauthorized"
}

Comment: Thanks. Now I am able to get the response. Thanks alot @ajb3ck